# XAMPP Error After add php_zip

Tags: windows, php, zip, xampp

I am using PHP 7.3. And need to generate a password-protected ZIP file.

After searching I know that PHP needs the *php_zip* extension to do this.
I do as the following instruction:

1. Download `php_zip.dll`
2. Extract `php_zip.dll` to `C:\xampp\php\ext`
3. Edit `php.ini` and add a new line `extension=php_zip.dll`
4. Restart Apache

But XAMPP shuts down unexpectedly with error:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 11152:tid 548] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: This is not an error but a warning. Please provide more logs.

Comment: I am sorry for posting this question. In PHP 7.3, it can generate a password-protected ZIP file, no need to  manually add ```php_zip.dll``` extension. Thanks dirdi for answering.